# C# | Como selecionar apenas algumas subpastas?

Tags: c#

Preciso buscar as informações de apenas algumas subpastas dentro de um diretório principal, fiz um código dessa forma mas estou com dificuldades para encontrar um jeito de informar apenas as subpastas que preciso.
Por exemplo tenho um pasta nesta estrutura:

**Pasta

|

|_ _ _ subpasta1/arquivos.xml

|

|_ _ _ subpasta2/arquivos.xml

|

|_ _ _ subpasta3/arquivos.xml**

Precisaria pegar os dados apenas da *subpasta1* e *subpasta3*, o código que tenho só consigo ler a *Pasta* inteira:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace LerDiretorios
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var directoryPath = @"C:\Pasta\";
            var searchPattern = "*.xml";
            var monthsAgo = -2;
            string[] filesFound;
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                filesFound = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                filesFound
                    .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
                    .Where(f => f.CreationTime >= f.CreationTime.AddMonths(monthsAgo))
                    .ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write($"ERRO: {ex.Message}");
                goto End;
            }

            if (filesFound.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nenhum arquivo encontrado.");
                goto End;
            }

            foreach (string filePath in filesFound)
            {
                FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{fInfo.Directory}, Arquivo: {Path.GetFileName(fInfo.Name)}, " +
                    $"Criado em: {fInfo.CreationTime.ToString()}\n");
            }

            //Conta os registros lidos
            Console.WriteLine($"Quantidade de registros lidos: {filesFound.Length}");

            //Mostra hora de início do procedimento
            Console.WriteLine($"Hora Inicio: {startTime.TimeOfDay}");

            //Mostra hora de fim do procedimento
            var finishTime = DateTime.Now; 
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Hora Fim: {finishTime.TimeOfDay} \n" +
                $"Tempo de Execução: {finishTime.TimeOfDay - startTime.TimeOfDay}");

        End:;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem tantas formas mas nada direto tem que passar o Path nesse caso separados já visto que você sabe qual deseja ler. Crie um array com os nomes da pastas e faça um for. Pergunto é várias pastas?

Comment: Como você faria se não fosse programação?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic são quase 60 subpastas, simplifiquei um pouco no exemplo, mas a lógica penso que seria a mesma para resolver. Vou tentar o for pra ver como fica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Observação: seu código pode ser refatorado e aperfeiçoado, porque pode por exemplo criar a lista de [FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) diretamente pela class [DirectoryInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8)</sup>

Se deseja especificar somente alguns diretórios para listar os seus arquivos dependendo do tipo utilize um argumento de `array` informando quais pastas precisa pesquisar, também vale lembrar que já existe um maneira de retornar [FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) de forma explicita, segue o exemplo abaixo:

Esse método primeiro retornar um `array` de [FileInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8):

```
private static FileInfo[] GetFiles(string[] paths, string search = "*.xml")
{
    FileInfo[] items = null;
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            items = (items == null)
                ? (new DirectoryInfo(path)).GetFiles(search)
                : items.Concat((new DirectoryInfo(path)).GetFiles(search)).ToArray();
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

E esse outro método imprime as informações do arquivo:

```
private static void PrintFileInfo(FileInfo[] fileInfos)
{
    if (fileInfos != null)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
             $"{fileInfo.DirectoryName} Arquivo: {fileInfo.Name}, " +
             $"Criado em: {fileInfo.CreationTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null)}\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nenhum dado para impressão");
    }
}
```

sempre tente dividir de uma maneira lógica que cada coisa faz, um pega os arquivos o outro mostra os arquivos e assim por diante, o reaproveitamento fica mais claro.

---

Como utilizar?

```
// Busca os arquivos
FileInfo[] items = GetFiles(new string[] { @"C:\", @"D:\" }, "*.txt");

//Mostra os arquivos com as suas informações
PrintFileInfo(items);
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [FileInfo Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8)
- [DirectoryInfo Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8)